# undeclared selector on multiple bar buttons

Tags: iphone, ios7, navigation, uinavigationbar

I am getting a warning of "undeclared selector deleteHorse" on the following data.   The application also fails on this warning.

ViewController.h file contains the following:

```
- (IBAction)deleteHorse:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)editHorse:(id)sender;
```

The ViewController.m file has the following:

```
- (void)deleteHorse:(id)sender
{
if(self.uniqueId > 0)
{
    self.eqDatabase = [[EQDatabase alloc] init];
    [eqDatabase initDatabase];

    EQHorseDetailsInfo *horsedetails = [[EQHorseDetailsInfo alloc] init];
    horsedetails.uniqueId = self.uniqueId;
    [eqDatabase deleteHorseData:horsedetails];

    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}
}

-(void)editHorse:(id)sender
{
NSLog(@"EditingHorse");
}


-(void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

UIBarButtonItem *deleteItem= [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
    initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemTrash
    target:self
    action:@selector(deleteHorse)];   ERROR IS HERE @selector
UIBarButtonItem *editItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]   
initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemEdit target:self 
action:@selector(editHorse)];  AND -(void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

UIBarButtonItem *deleteItem= [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
    initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemTrash
    target:self
    action:@selector(deleteHorse)];
UIBarButtonItem *editItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]  
initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemEdit target:self  
action:@selector(editHorse)];

NSArray *actionButtonItems = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:deleteItem, editItem,
nil];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = actionButtonItems;
}


NSArray *actionButtonItems = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:deleteItem, editItem,
nil];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = actionButtonItems;
}
```

---

I have done a search on this.

Comment: Thank you so very much for the help.   Very happy. This is my first question ever.  Is there anything more I should be doing for you besides thanking you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `:` for the selector since your `deleteHorse` has a parameter:

```
UIBarButtonItem *deleteItem= [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
    initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemTrash
    target:self
    action:@selector(deleteHorse:)];
```